# Akka doesn't load application.conf

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am trying to set a different `akka.http.parsing.max-chunk-size`

My application.conf is in src/resources/ and looks like this:

```
akka.http {
   parsing {
       max-chunk-size=20m
   }
}
```

I am using this code in my main to set up my system:

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer() 
implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
```

However I still get this error when trying to make a big get request:

```
akka.http.scaladsl.model.EntityStreamException: HTTP chunk size exceeds the configured limit of 1048576 bytes
```

EDIT: I have tried relocating the file based on the answer I got, however i still get the same error. My program structure looks like this:

```
├── main
│   ├── resources
│   │   └── application.conf
│   └── scala
│       ├── program
│       │   ├── BackTester.scala
│       │   ├── Main.scala
│       │   └── StrategyExecutor.scala
│       ├── strategies
│       │   ├── BollingerBandStrategy.scala
│       │   ├── CrossingSMAStrategy.scala
│       │   ├── RSIStrategy.scala
│       │   ├── StochasticStrategy.scala
│       │   └── TradingStrategies.scala
│       └── util
│           ├── Interval.scala
│           ├── JsonParser.scala
│           ├── Time.scala
│           ├── barseries
│           │   └── barSeriesBuilder.scala
│           └── requests
│               └── Fetcher.scala
└── test
    └── scala
```

Comment: Try using `akka.http.server.parsing`, `akka.http.client.parsing` or `akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.parsing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the official website and it looks like the configuration is correct (
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html
). I would put inside an specific application into the application.conf file. Like this example here below.

```
routersDemo {
  akka {
    actor.deployment {
      /poolMaster2 {
        router = round-robin-pool
        nr-of-instances = 5
      }

      /groupMaster2 {
        router = round-robin-group
        routees {
          paths = ["/user/slave_1","/user/slave_2","/user/slave_3","/user/slave_4","/user/slave_5"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then call it at the ConfigFactory

```
    val system = ActorSystem("routersDemo", ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("routersDemo"))
```